# Ruby on Rails 'add to favorites' (with AJAX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to do 'add to favorites' (with AJAX) feature in my Ruby on Rails app (marketplace), anyone knows what's the best methodology? I did get suggested, 'acts as votable' gem but this looks like a vote system not like a record keeper. SOS

Comment: Create a model which has references to user and product, than add a correspond controller to CRUD user's favorite products

Comment: just add a model `Favourite` making user `has_many :favourites`. Don't afraid to do it from scratch.

Comment: I have done the model and references, would you happen to know the AJAX?

Comment: post the part of html where you have each product having heart button or whatever  and controller method that accepts that request

Comment: I dont have the controller defined, the html is just cards with a disable linked_to and a 'plus' icon which is what I hope to be the favorites

Comment: please include my nickname in comments by doing `@seethrough`, thus i will be notified of your comment. Secondly, just post the html for product including `for` loop, perhaps omitting some parts not related to question.

Comment: @seethrough thanks, the HTML would be irrelevant. I would need the JS to make my favorites icons react with AJAX and not re-render the page....I am building this in Rails btw.. thanks